# My favorite place was/is Gardens by the bay. (back shifting)

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, backshifting

I was asked to talk about a beautiful place I visited. I said:

I went to Singapore last January..... (this is where I got and get confused all the time)

1. *It **was** a very beautiful place*. - I back shifted even though it's still a beautiful place.
2. *In fact **it's** one of the most beautiful countries in the world.* - I didn't back shift here because it's a fact but I got confused because I had back shifted (was a beautiful place) right before this sentence.
3. *My favorite place **was** Gardens by the bay.* - It's still my favorite but since I was talking about the past and the question asked me to describe a past event I though back shifting would be correct.
4. *It **had** three gigantic greenhouses.* - again the same problem as 3. It still has three greenhouses.

Please let me know if all my sentences were correct given the context.

Comment: Do you *know* it still has those three greenhouses? I found a lovely spot in one place but when I went back there a couple of years later it had been rebuilt. So it *was* my favourite place in that city, but if I keep visiting somewhere frequently, then it *is* my favourite place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences are all fine.

When you are talking about a place that still exists in the present but you experienced at a particular time in the past, you often have a choice of whether to speak about your feelings for it in the past or present tense.

You could say that a place you visited ***was*** very beautiful, referring to your experience on the visit, or you could say that it ***is*** very beautiful, reflecting the opinion you now hold of the place.

The only thing that might shape your choice of tense is whether you intend to visit a place again. For example, if you regularly visit a place it makes sense to say "I *love* it there"; whereas if you visited a place once and have no plans to return you are more likely to say "I *loved* it there".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't think 2 can be back shifted can it?